# Display text on screen - relative to launched command?

Tags: interface, text-object

I was thinking yesterday that it might be useful to see some text displayed somewhere on the screen when you execute certain commands in Blender. For example if you enter "Keep Uv and edit mesh mode selection in sync" mode Blender could display a text that says "Sync Mode - On" on your screen, have anyone seen any script that has this function? Is this day dreaming on my part or is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

In the past there was a screen cast add on.
Here is some history.

http://www.blendernation.com/2014/07/02/screencast-keys-addon-is-removed-b3d/

The info window type shows user operations.  The default vertical size of the window was increased to see the contents.

[image]

Python Script Software writers find this useful.